# Weird behavior with expressions JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Someone can explain to me why this happen? And please, if someone know this behavior name, please edit the title.

With this code:

```
 const arr = ['RIPA'], varB = "RIPB";
let _params;
_params && Array.isArray(_params) ? arr.push(..._params) : 
arr.push(_params);

_params && console.log("I will never appear");
varB && console.log("I will appear");

arr.push(varB);
console.log('array',arr);
console.log("Type of the _params --> ", typeof _params);
```

Output:

```
array [ 'RIPA', undefined, 'RIPB' ]
Type of the _params -->  undefined
```

jsBIN:
https://jsbin.com/bawepasivo/edit?js,console 
repl.it:
https://repl.it/GaHX

If the `_params` is `undefined`, how possible is of executing the second expression, if the `&&` expression returns the first false and the last trusty value.

Comment: `arr.push(_params)` pushed `undefined` in `arr`

Comment: What exactly is your question, it's a bit unclear. `_params && Array.isArray(_params)` evaluates to `false`, so `arr.push(_params);` is called, which pushes `undefined` to `arr`.

Comment: But the && expression returns the first falsy value, so in my thoughts, the compiler can never execute the second part of the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is executed like this:

`(_params && Array.isArray(_params)) ? arr.push(..._params) : arr.push(_params);`

But you meant probably this:

`_params && (Array.isArray(_params) ? arr.push(..._params) : arr.push(_params));`

You just have to add parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

```
 false  && false                  ? never executed       : _params is undefined
_params && Array.isArray(_params) ? arr.push(..._params) : arr.push(_params);
```

other way:

```
if (_params && Array.isArray(_params)) { // (false && false) === false
    arr.push(..._params); // it will be never executed
} else {
    arr.push(_params); // _params is undefined
}
```

Comment: A, I saw the expression in another angle, I saw it like this `_params && (Array.isArray(_params) ? arr.push(..._params) : arr.push(_params));`

Answer (score 1):

```
let _params; // undefined
```

`_params && Array.isArray(_params) ?` is `false`, so the called code is `arr.push(_params);`, resulting in `arr.push(undefined);`